# Scaling up an old dos game to fit my screen? win7

Tags: windows-7, ms-dos, scaling

It is Oregon Trail 1.2 downloaded from myabandonware.com. The game works fine but the 4.3 aspect ratio of it makes for a tiny game window. It works straight out of the box on win7, so no dosbox needed. I tried using target line parameters to stretch the window but nothing changed, still sitting at 640x480. Ideally I would like to get it up to at least 960x720.

Comment: What happens when you try to run it full screen? Does the graphics driver or the monitor stretch it?  (Mine do not but I had to turn that off in both places for a similar problem).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't switch to the video to a low-res DOS-compatible mode so you can run old programs full-screen, like you could in XP. (Apparently you can if you switch the video driver to Standard VGA, but that's a hack.)

Try using the screen Magnifier feature, intended as a low-vision aid. Open the Start menu and type/search for "Ease of Access Center". When you open that, click Start Magnifier.

The Magnifier starts at 200% in Full Screen View. You can try scaling that up to 300% or more, depending on your screen. You might also change the Options (the gear icon) so that Tracking follows Keyboard Focus instead of or in addition to the Mouse.

If you lose your place, type <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to disable the Magnifier.